# Is this a correct WSDL declaration?

Tags: java, wsdl

I have a response like :

```
** <code>['123']</code> **
```

and here is my wsdl declaration is :

**

```
<xsd:complexType name="Type">
                <xsd:all>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="isSuccess" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="code" type="xsd:integer"/>
                </xsd:all>
      </xsd:complexType>
```

**
Is this a correct declaration?

and i handle it in JAVA like :

```
protected BigInteger code;
@XmlElement(required = true)
```

How to declare integer array in WSDL and how to handle in JAVA?

thanks in advance.

Comment: There is `wsimport` tool that can generate java artifacts from the given wsdl.

Answer (score 0):

Declare Integer array in xsd as below

```
<xsd:element name="numbers">
  <xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:list itemType="xsd:integer" />
  </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

Define your numbers property in Java class as below with setters and getters

```
@XmlElement(required = true)
private List<Integer> numbers;
```

xml is `<numbers>3 6 5</numbers>`